# How to use PowerShell to check WSUS updates status

Tags: powershell, wsus, windows-update

Usually I get a **list of** Windows updates **KB numbers** which I have to check the **approval status** on WSUS server for.

So for me it is very annoying (and time consuming) to open WSUS console and then search for each of it...

Please help me - **How to retrieve the WSUS update by KB using PowerShell ?**

My idea is to have a script which takes list of KB numbers and for each of the KB numbers tells me if the update is approved (**or list the groups to which the update was approved is also acceptable**).

Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 2):

You need install the `UpdateServices` module which is available since Server 2012:

```
Import-Module -Name UpdateServices
```

Then you can use `Get-WsusUpdate`

Here is the [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/wsus/get-wsusupdate?view=win10-ps)

---

Example: Use this to get the needed but unapproved critical updates

```
Get-WsusUpdate -Classification Critical -Approval Unapproved -Status Needed
```

---

Example: Check whether `KB2952664` is approved:

```
Get-WsusUpdate -Classification Critical -Approval Approved | where {$_.update.Title -like "*KB2952664*"}
```